# Evict and contains on Cache in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA,if I have two entity classes Account and CheckingAccount,such that CheckingAccount extends Account.I have a CheckingAccount entity instance with primary key of 10.

```
Cache c=//get a reference to caache from entity manager factory
c.evict(Account.class,10);
boolean flag1=c.contains(Account.class,10);
boolean flag2=c.contains(CheckingAccount.class,10);
```

will the value of both flags be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `c.contains(Account.class,10)` certainly will be false - you either have removed this entity from cache or it does not exist.

Second one `c.contains(CheckingAccount.class,10)` **can** be true if this entity has been put into cache.

The version of `evict` method which takes second argument works only for given entity of given id. It is not the same as `Cache#evict(Class)` which removes all entities along with them subclasses from cache.